# Problem with debugging of java program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I made a (rather big) java desktop program in Eclipse.
A could normal run an debug program.
But after making changes in the program (to many to easily undone the changes), I tried debugging the program, but the program crashes. Eclipse doesn't give feedback or problems.
After a few minutes (sometimes, not always), my frame appaers, but without content.
I can normally run the program, and also I can debugging other programs with Eclipse.

Can anyone give me suggestions where I can start looking?
I should think something like a stack overflow question, but why can I run the application, but not debug?

Debugging informations is as follows;

```
    framePackage.Program at localhost:38643 
        Thread [AWT-EventQueue-1] (Running) 
        Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)    
        Daemon Thread [Thread-0] (Running)  
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (28 apr. 2021 21:48:09)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try and step through the code, and set break points. Yes I understand the application might be big, but I'm sure there's multiple classes/methods and you know how each interacts.

Stepping through the code may give an indication of what is and is not working as it should. For future reference, if you're using Eclipse, I'd suggest checking out some debugging tools from the Eclipse Market Place.

Comment: Since a  week, i can debug my program. So my problem is solved.

Comment: But why I couldn't before, I don't know, I used logging while programming  because debugging didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can go step by step.
But it goes so slowly, I think in particular the steps that do the layout, making a tabbedPane, myFrame.pack() ...